# Android JSONObject need print null

Tags: java, android, json

data from:

`{"i":"One","o":"two","u":"","a":"four"}`

code:

```
JSONObject data;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
  data = list.optJSONObject(i);
  mSearchList.add(data.optString("o") + " " + 
            data.optString("u")+ " " + data.optString("a"));
}
```

print:

`i=one
 o=two
 u=
 a=four`

I need print:

`i=one
 o=two
 u=null
 a=four`

how to do?Thank you read my question ,please help me

Comment: Check if it's an empty string, print `null` instead...

Comment: If you have Guava, you can use `Strings.emptyToNull()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios Delimanolis said, you can check if that is a empty string, return "null" text.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
  data = list.optJSONObject(i);
  mSearchList.add(
            data.optString("o").equals("") ? "null" : data.optString("o") + " " + 
            data.optString("u").equals("") ? "null" : data.optString("u") + " " + 
            data.optString("a").equals("") ? "null" : data.optString("a"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
getValidString(JSONObject json,String key){
    String value="";
    try{
      value=json.getString(key);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(value.length==0){
      value="null";
    }
}
```